# Bcrypt() with Zend Framework 1.12.x

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, bcrypt

Is there a possibility to use `Bcrypt()` in Zend Framework 1.12.x?

I've found `Zend\Crypt\Password\Bcrypt` for Zend version 2.1.3 but nothing similar for the 1.12.x version.

Generally asking: Is there an alternative for handling password as explained [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.crypt.password.html) for Zend version 1.12.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement your own AuthAdapter, but someone has done the task for you and backported the ZF2 BcCrypt Adapter to Zend Framework 1.1x.

You can get it on gitHub: [BcCrypt Zend Framework 1.x](https://github.com/rumeau/zf1-authadapter-dbtablebcrypt)